# How can I complete The Outland Count's Task?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-4

One of the first missions I received is The Outland Count's Task, which is to find a kapok grove in the Windy Plains. I've sailed my airship to a kapok grove right on the line of A2/A3, but when I return to town I can't turn the quest in. It's behaving as if I didn't find the grove.

How do I complete this quest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that you need to first talk to the guy at Mark Grand Court so he can tell you the coordinates of the grove before it will let you "discover" it.

After talking to him and then going back to what I'd already found, I got some new text regarding the quest. I then had to talk to the guy again and point to the grove on the map before turning the quest in.